# VB While File Exists, Change FileName

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file-io

just looking for some help on this. I've tried a few different things and I'm stumped. I'm trying to take a check if a file exists in a directory, and if it does, then I want to rename add `- Copy` to the file name. Then it should check again if there is a conflict, and if there isn't it should move the file. Sounds simple enough, but it isn't working at all. Since I can't convert from `String` to `DirectoryInfo`, I have to declare multiple variables, and it just doesn't feel right. What can I do to fix this?

```
Dim fileExt As String = ""

Dim oldFileName As String = file.FullName
Dim newFileName As String = oldFileName
Dim newFileLocation = Environment.GetSpecialFolder(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures) + "\" + file.Name

While FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(newFileLocation) 'While File exists in new directory
    'Add copy to filename
    fileExt = fileType.Replace("*", "")
    newFileName = newFileName.Remove(newFileName.LastIndexOf("."), (newFileName.Length - newFileName.LastIndexOf(".")))
    newFileName += " - Copy"
    newFileName += fileExt

    'Rename file
    FileSystem.Rename(oldFileName, newFileName)

    'Declare a new DirInf variable because I can't use a string to set one
    Dim newFile As New DirectoryInfo(newFileName)

    'Move the new file to 
    newFile.MoveTo("C:\Users\" + Environ("USERNAME") + "\Pictures\")
    ProgressBar.Value += 1
End While
```

Comment: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`

Comment: @SLaks Thank you. That makes it a little simpler. I'll update that in just a second.

Comment: @SLaks Actually, on second thought, wouldn't this method be better? I need to keep the file extension, so I can add it back on later.

Comment: Hmmm... `newFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(newFileName, "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `File.Move()`, which takes two strings.

Also, `"C:\Users\" + Environ("USERNAME") + "\Pictures\"` is very wrong; many users do not have `C:` drives.
You should call `Environment.GetSpecialFolder(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)`

Comment: So with the `File.Move()` method I could rename the file, during the move. Correct? Fe. `File.Move("C:\1.txt", "C:\1-Copy.txt")`

Comment: Alright, I should be able to work with that, give me a minute.

Comment: Are you using VS 2012? Because `Environment.GetSpecialFolder()` throws an error. I am using 2010.

Comment: Error 2 'GetSpecialFolder' is not a member of 'System.Environment'. C:\Users\Josh\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Program_Name\Program_Name\Main.vb 114 53 Program_Name